# What is difference between RegAsm.exe and regsvr32? How to generate a tlb file using regsvr32?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com, regasm

Can any body tell me what is the difference between regsvr32 and RegAsm? My Dll is in C#, so how can I import the classes to c++?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`regsvr32` will load the library and try to call the `DllRegisterServer()` from that library. It doesn't care what `DllRegisterServer()` actually does - it just calls that function and checks the returned value. You use it to register COM servers in unmanaged DLLs. It can't generate a .tlb file.

`regasm` will register a COM-exposed .NET assembly as a COM server. You use it for .NET assemblies. It can generate a .tlb file given the assembly only - it inspects the type infromation stored in the assembly and includes the COM-exposed entities into the type library.

Comment: @Aamir: When I first tried to make a COM-exposed assembly and consume it from a VC++ application and make this application redistributable I had a similar set of question. The difference is that Stackoverflow.com was launched later.