# Using COM dll in VC++ dll

Tags: c#, visual-c++, com

I have created a COM dll in C#.net, and calling a method of COM dll from VCPP code.

The creation of COM dll also result in a tlb file creation, after reading about it found that I need to register the tlb file using regasm to make a registry entry of it.

Now if I am running the application on a machine where Microsoft Visual Studio is not installed, then I wont be able to register the tlb file using regasm, also when I attempt to register the tlb file using regsvr32 its giving an error message.

Is there a work around for it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to register the .tlb file - you have to use `regasm` with `/codebase` parameter to register the COM .dll file. You need to run `regasm` on every machine where you want to use your COM .dll via COM. `regasm` is shipped and installed with .NET framework, so if it's not available it means you can't use your COM DLL since the latter requires .NET runtime anyway.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1163503).

Comment: I have done the development on a developer machine and  now i would like to test it on windows server 2008 without visual studio installed and took all the binaries(depended dll(s), COM dll and tlb file and also the .exe file written in VCPP to call COM method),could you please tell me how should i proceed to test the exe

Comment: You'll need the VC++ reditributable and .NET framework on that machine. You'll have to copy both the .dll and the program .exe there, register the .dll with regasm and run the .exe.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!I am able to register the COM dll using Regasm.exe , but when i try to register the same COM dll on 64 bit machine i am getting the following  exception RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load 'C:\Binaries\GCOM.dll' be
cause it is not a valid .NET assembly. I used the below cmd o register the dll G:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe GCOM.dll /tlb:GCOM.tlb /codebase

Comment: Got It!! I am able to register it on 64 bit machine. Build the COM dll with Any CPU.