# IIS8 Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3' at Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Tags: iis, asp-classic, adodb, createobject

I get the following error:

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>   Server.CreateObject Failed
>   /loadHome.asp, line 15
>   800401f3

Line 15 is

```
Set checkUser = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

I am using .NET Framework 4.0, also registered it.

In the IIS Application Pools Defaults I set Enable 32-Bit Applications to True and in the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions the framework is allowed.

Any ideas, why this error happens?

Comment: A permission issue is the usual suspect. Not sure which ones are needed for your server but I'd suggest you use Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to check out any errors on C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado

Comment: Hi, sry for my late answer.
The Process Monitor doesn't contain an entry with "ado" :/

Also tried this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269076/server-createobject-failed-in-classic-asp
but didn't help :(