# Error when trying to create a server object in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, com-object

The .dll is ASPCache_x64.dll, in C:\Windows\System32 (I know; this decision was made before my time.)

The server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 VirtualBox VM with IIS 7.5, on a host running Windows 7. The website in question is a classic ASP site running under .NET Framework 2.0. The VM itself is a copy of a VM we use as a template, and no one else using a copy of that machine is having this problem.

**The problem:**
On loading any page, I get the following error:

```
ERROR IN PROCESSING: ?
ASP Code:
Number: 0
Source:
Line
Number: 0
Description: Create object failed
ASP Description: An error occurred while creating object 'myCache'.
```

**Other information:**

- eventually traced to Global.asa `<object>` tag
- attempting to create and use an ASPCache object in a VBScript file run from a desktop folder works fine
- attempting to create and use an ASPCache object on a test ASP page in the same domain gives me the same error until I refresh the page, at which point I get this error:

*(workaround for broken markdown; ignore this line)*

```
ERROR IN PROCESSING: /test_createobject.asp
ASP Code:
Number: -2146959359 
Source: 
Line Number: 4 
Description: Cannot create ASPCache object - a required component is missing. Please reinstall your software.
```

**I have tried:**

- downloading a fresh copy of the VM
- making sure IUSR has read and execute permissions on C:\Windows\Systeme32\ASPCache-x64.dll
- de-registering and re-registering C:\Windows\Systeme32\ASPCache-x64.dll with regsvr32.exe
- granting IUSR read permission on the ASPCache and ASPCache.1 registry keys
- applying the fix found here: [Server.CreateObject Failed in Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269076/server-createobject-failed-in-classic-asp)
- checking every setting I can think of against our shared dev environment, which doesn't have this problem
- restarting IIS after every change
- restarting the computer after all of the above
- granting individual app pools read and execute permissions on C:\Windows\Systeme32\ASPCache-x64.dll
- changing the default application pool identity to NetworkService
- changing the default application pool identity to [Machine name]\Administrator

I've been Googling this problem on and off for months. Nothing I've found has helped.

---

Code for the test asp page, which doesn't work:

```
<%
Dim testCache

Set testCache = Server.CreateObject("ASPCache")
testCache("Marco") = "Polo"
Response.Write testCache("Marco")
%>
```

Code for the VB Script, which does work:

```
Dim testCache
Set testCache = CreateObject("ASPCache")

testCache("Marco") = "Polo"
WScript.echo o("Marco")
```

Relevant code in Global.asa, which gives the original error:

```
<OBJECT RUNAT=Server SCOPE=Application ID=TestCache PROGID=ASPCache></OBJECT>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: That looks like a 64 bit dll. Do you have 32 bit applications enabled in your app pool, because that seems to disable 64 bit ones?

Comment: Disabling 32-bit applications didn't help.

Comment: Post updated with code.