# The module ".dll" was loaded but the entry-point was not found

Tags: asp.net, dll, windows-7, regsvr32, component-services

I have a DLL which cause to an error when I run the application.
The error says that the service is not registered. So I run command `regsvr32` with the name of the DLL.
But it gives me an error, now the error is:

> The module 'mydll.dll' was loaded but the entry-point 'DllRegisterServer' was not found.
>
> Make sure that 'mydll.dll' is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again

I worked on Windows 7 64-bit. On Windows XP it works fine!.
Does someone know what it can be?
Thanks!

Answer (score -13, accepted):

I found the answer:
I need to add a new application to the service components in my computer and then add the right DLL's.

Thanks!
If anyone has the same problem, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Hi I am having the same problem please provide me a way ahead.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: any update on the "some more explanations" ? What do you mean by "add a new application to the service components" ?

Comment: Please elaborate clearly how you solved the problem.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is "Hey, I found an answer, I am willing to provide an answer if anyone needs it!" It would have been nice if you included an answer in your answer.

Comment: What is this mystery.

Comment: @st mnmn could you please explain a little bit better what was your solution?

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the DLL is either not a COM DLL or it's corrupt. If it's not a COM DLL and not being used as a COM DLL by an application then there is no need to register it.
From what you say in your question `(the service is not registered)` it seems that we are talking about a service not correctly installed. I will try to reinstall the application.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and

```
dumpbin /exports mydll.dll
```

and

```
depends mydll.dll
```

showed 'DllRegisterServer'.

The problem was that there was another DLL in the system that had the same name.
After renaming mydll the registration succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

What solved it for me was using :

> regasm.exe 'xx.dll' /tlb /codebase /register

It is however, important to understand the difference between regasm.exe and regsvr.exe:

[What is difference between RegAsm.exe and regsvr32? How to generate a tlb file using regsvr32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163503/what-is-difference-between-regasm-exe-and-regsvr32-how-to-generate-a-tlb-file-u)

Comment: The OP said that `regsvr32` worked on WinXP, but not on Win7 64. So this is not the reason.

Comment: Why do you need to understand the difference between regasm and regsvr if your solution solved the registration of the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the command prompt window has admin permissions.  I am using Windows Server 2012 and was getting the error when using regsvr32 in the command prompt.  I opened the command prompt by right clicking on it from  All Programs/Windows System/Command Prompt and selecting "run as administrator"  Running regsvr32 in this window successfully loaded the dll file.