# Trying to Import FoxPro DBF File to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, foxpro, dbf, openrowset

As the title says, I'm trying to import a FoxPro dbf file into sql server using openrowset. At first I tried to export the DBF to an xls file and import using the Import/Export wizard. This works pretty well normally, but there is one field that sometimes holds a really long string, and this string is being truncated at 4096 characters during the export from the dbf to xls.

I found an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52822/how-to-import-a-dbf-file-in-sql-server) with instructions on how to do this using openrowset.

When I try the first answer:

```
select *
from openrowset('MSDASQL', 'Driver=Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver;
SourceDB=\\path\;
SourceType=DBF',
'select * from TABLE.DBF')
```

I get the error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "(null)".
```

When I try the second answer:

```
select *
from openrowset('VFPOLEDB',
'\\Path\';'';'',
'select * from TABLE.DBF')
```

I get the error:

```
Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB" has not been registered.
```

I tried to register the OLE*.dll files manually with regsvr32, but only some of them worked. On ole32, oleacc, oleaut32, and oleprn I got a success message. On oleacchooks, oleaccrc, oledlg, and oleres I got this error:

```
The module "oleacchooks" was loaded but the
entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "oleacchooks" is a valid DLL or OCX file
and then try again
```

After [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227448/the-module-dll-was-loaded-but-the-entry-point-was-not-found) [investigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680308(v=vs.85).aspx) I tried to install the componet, but when I tried to install the msi file for FoxPro ([found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vfoxpro/bb190232)), I got this error:

```
An error occurred while processing the last operation.
Error code 80110408 - Error occurred reading the application file

The event log may contain additional troubleshooting information.
```

So, I'm officially lost here. Does anybody have suggestions on how to get openrowset to work, or some other way of importing the dbf file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pat, you can use DBF Commander Pro for this task.

[Download it](http://dbf-software.com/download.html), install, then click File -> Export to DBMS. In the window appears click Build button in order to build the connection string: select MS OLEDB Provider for SQL Server, then choose your server from the list, provide login and password, select a database, click OK:

[image]

In the Export to DBMS window select the destination table you want to import source DBF file to, then click Export.

More info on import and export DBF to a database you can find [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS).

P.S. The app has **fully functional** free trial 20-days period.

Comment: This seems to have done it. Thanks a ton. I've been struggling with this for a couple days. I'll talk to my boss about purchasing a license.

Answer (score 0):

Try using VFPOLEDB.1 as the provider. You may be experiencing driver version issues.

Comment: Same error unfortunately.    Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "VFPOLEDB.1" has not been registered.

Comment: @Pat, you probably have to download the VFP OleDB provider from Microsoft, then go with it...

Comment: @DRapp Thanks, but I already did that. I also uninstalled/reinstalled a couple times. That is where I got the ole*.dll files from. Found it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vfoxpro/bb190232