# Visual Fox Pro - Data Export to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-migration, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have a potential new client with data in a 2.6 version of FoxPro (16 bit). They want to migrate this to sql server.

I have looked around to try and build up my knowledge about this but I am confused about a number of things.

Most of the articles I have read talk about Visual Fox Pro and use of Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro. I dont fully understand the differences between Fox Pro (16 bit) and visual Fox Pro so I cant make a judgment call on whether this approach will work.

Does anyone have a tried and tested approach for this?

Kind Regards,

Mark

Comment: Most likely you've got a regular DBF database, but its type is old. Did you try to open it with a DBF editor?

Comment: I dont have access to any of the clients files at the moment. We are in an investigation phase and thus cant access their systems.

Comment: I'd recommend you to ask your client to provide a sample DBF file in order to you could try to work with it. Also, please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727768/trying-to-import-foxpro-dbf-file-to-sql-server/19731182#19731182).

Comment: Getting a sample is on the cards. Hopefully we should get that soon. To be clear though - what differences should I expect when using "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro". Should I be able to use that against a 2.6 version of FoxPro?

Comment: Yes, this provider should work correctly with any version of DBF, even with 2.x.