# how convert foxpro(dbf , dbc) file to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, converters, foxpro

i want to convert several Table from foxpro (dbf , dbc) file
to sql server. how can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try following links it will help you

[Trying to Import FoxPro DBF File to SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727768/trying-to-import-foxpro-dbf-file-to-sql-server)

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2011/import-dbf-files/

Answer (score 0):

You can import dbf file to sql . you can follow instructions given [Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2463/importing-dbf-files-into-sql-server/).

you can just Google `import foxpro to sql server` .. you can find so many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck using the [upsizing wizard](https://vfpx.codeplex.com/releases/view/10224). This tool I believe was included within one of the later versions of the Visual FoxPro IDE and appears now to be supported by the VFPx project on codeplex.

Comment: If you're going to use the Upsizing Wizard, make sure to get the one from the VFPX project, not the one that shipped with VFP prior to VFP9 SP2.