# Register 32-bit COM server (and generate TLB) for use with 32-bit and 64-bit clients

Tags: windows, com, regasm

**Method 1: x86 target platform**

I have a .NET class library that is intended for use with both 32-bit and 64-bit clients, some of which are .NET projects and some of which are C++ MFC projects. I can get the library to work with the 32-bit clients, but the 64-bit clients get a "Class not registered" exception. Poking around the registry, it looks like only the win32 key is being set (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib{GUID}\1.0\0\win32).

Some notes on a few of my settings:

- "Register for COM interop" is checked.
- "Make assembly COM-Visible" is checked.
- The "Platform target" is x86.
- The library contains a 32-bit unmanaged DLL that loads methods with DLLImport.
- The C++ MFC clients use `#import "MyLibrary.tlb"` to marshall the interop code.
- I have not made any changes to the code to support COM. (E.g., I have not overridden System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install.)

In an effort to resolve this, I have tried several things based on some research and investigation.

**Method 2: "Any CPU" target platform**

First, I tried setting the Platform target to "Any CPU". In this case, both the win32 and win64 keys are set in the registry, and the 64-bit client can talk to the COM server. However, when I do this, I get the error "An attempt was made to load a program with the incorrect format." This is due to the 32-bit unmanaged DLL, which requires that I build the project with x86.

**Method 3: Obtain a 64-bit build of my library's unmanaged DLL dependency**

To work around this, I could potentially get a hold of the 64-bit build of the unmanaged DLL. However, we have purchased this DLL from a third party, and for whatever reason, they charge a large, additional fee for the 64-bit build of the DLL. On top of the explicit cost, I would also have to [implement DLLImport calls for each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852634/using-a-32bit-or-64bit-dll-in-c-sharp-dllimport) and call according to whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit, which would triple the number of methods in my wrapper class. Thus, while this is a possible solution, it's far from desirable, and from what I understand about COM, this shouldn't be necessary.

**Method 4: regsvr32.exe**

The most common solution I find online for this is to use regsvr32.exe to manually register an application for both 32-bit and 64-bit interop. However, I need the TLB file for interoperability with my MFC clients, and [apparently regsvr32 doesn't support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163503/what-is-difference-b-w-regasm-exe-and-regsvr32-how-to-generate-a-tlb-file-usi).

**Method 5: regasm.exe**

To get the TLB file and hopefully register for both 32-bit and 64-bit interop, I have also tried using regasm.exe to register the assembly manually. I used the following command to do this.

`"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe" "D:\Path\To\MyLibrary.dll" /tlb /nologo`

However, this registers *only* the 64-bit COM server and the win32 COM registry key is missing. Now my 32-bit client can't find the COM server and says "Class not registered." Furthermore, for the 64-bit client, I get the same error that I saw when I selected "Any CPU": "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

---

**TL;DR** How do I register a 32-bit COM server for use with both 32-bit and 64-bit client applications? (Noting that I need the TLB file, and that the server needs to load an unmanaged, 32-bit DLL.)

---

I think I should clarify the architecture here. Here's a diagram that demonstrates how I want these components to function.

[image]

As you can see, I need 64-bit code to interact with 32-bit code by means of a COM server, which, as @MC-ND notes, is supposed to work. How should I configure my COM server to support this?

Comment: Note the "Framework64" in the Regasm.exe path you used.  That means you used the 64-bit version, it only writes the keys that can be seen by a 64-bit client app.  You have to use %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe (no 64) to write the 32-bit keys in Wow6432Node.  There's no magic fix for trying to load 32-bit unmanaged code into a 64-bit process, that's just not possible.  Nor would there be much point in your supplier developing the 64-bit version if that could work of course.  Software engineers can't live on sun and air alone.

Comment: @HansPassant, I included a diagram; does this clear up what I'm trying to accomplish? My understanding is that COM servers allow 64-bit code to interact with 32-bit code. See [the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384231%28VS.85%29.aspx) that MD ND provided. That is what I'm trying to accomplish with my COM server.

Comment: check [this](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN: Process Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384231%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> On 64-bit Windows, a 64-bit process cannot load a 32-bit dynamic-link
>   library (DLL). Additionally, a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL

Your best option seems to compile your component as a 32bit out of process COM server.

Comment: I *am* using a COM server. Any idea what I'm doing wrong such that it isn't working like it should?

Comment: @DavidEnglund, i think, maybe,  we two are [not talking about the same](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Are you using an *out of process*, *.EXE*, COM Server?

Comment: An update: I have developed a proof-of-concept out-of-process COM server that works for all 4 client configurations (32-bit/64-bit, managed/unmanaged) that I have. To support unmanaged clients, I modified [the example, CSExeCOMServer,](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977996) to output a TLB file using a post-build event and `regasm`.

Comment: The answer to this question *is* still that a 32-bit out-of-process COM server is needed, so I will accept it. However, after 3 days of trying, I have not been able to get this to work with the system default surrogate, "dllhost.exe", and I need to move on. I wish I had been able to write up an answer with the actual solution, but sadly I don't have one. See my previous comment for sample code that *almost* got me there.

Comment: @DavidEnglund, Sorry, seems i did not explain it clear enough. Your only real "problem" is that you have a 32bit DLL and it can only be loaded by a 32bit process. You can build anything you want around this, keeping your proof-of-concept server to expose the required interface to the rest of the world, but, under it, the 32 bit process is a requirement as long as the 32bit dll is used.